# Integrating FBConnect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am integrating the facebook API i.e, FBConnect to post message on my wall,I have integrated the FBConnect API  in it, I am getting the Fb login screen but m not getting the post to wall dialog after. Can you tel whats the problem? How can i solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can post msg on your wall using these lines

```
FBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Enter your message:";
   [dialog show];
```

if you want to post some image then use dialog.attachment and for any hyperlink you can use dialog.actionLinks.